# Friend Function Accessibility Issue

Tags: c++, friend

I am trying to make a friend function for another class, but my current layout is causing access issues and header-include issues.

In my project I have two files: Class A and Class B. For the sake of brevity, everything is inlined in the header file, as it still demonstrates my issue.

```
#ifndef CLASSA
#define CLASSA

#include "ClassB.h"

class A {
   private:
      int x;
   public:
      A(int x) {
          this->x = x;
      }
      friend void testFriend(A in);
};

#endif

#pragma once
#ifndef CLASSB
#define CLASSB
#include <cstdio>
#include "ClassA.h"

class B {
public:
   void testFriend(A in) {
       printf("%d", in.x);
   }
};
#endif
```

However, with this setup, Visual Studio thinks that class A's private member elements are inaccessible despite it being a member function. Furthermore, they are including each other which will cause errors eventually. This setup works fine when these two classes are in the same header file, though. How can I achieve a setup like this, where one class has a member function that needs to be a friend with another class, and while having the two classes be in separate header files.

Comment: `friend void testFriend(A in);` is unrelated to `B::testFriend`

Comment: You befriended a lone function `void testFriend(A in)` and not the one from B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration

```
friend void testFriend(A in);
```

makes a non-member function named `testFriend` a `friend` of the class. It does not make `B::testFriend` a `friend` of class A.

You can solve the problem by making `B` a `friend` of `A`. This will require only a forward declaration.

```
#ifndef CLASSA
#define CLASSA

// No need for this.
// #include "ClassB.h"
class B;

class A {
   private:
      int x;
   public:
      A(int x) {
          this->x = x;
      }

      // This does not work.
      // friend void testFriend(A in);

      // Make B a friend of the class.
      friend B;
};

#endif
```

Now,

```
class B {
public:
   void testFriend(A in) {
       printf("%d", in.x);
   }
};
```

should work just fine.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. Is there any way to make just testFriend(A in) a friend instead of the whole class?

Comment: @user1939991, yes you can but then the definition of `B` has to be visible to `A`. See [the answer by @schoe001](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48673745/434551) for that. You cannot forward declare a member function of a class.

Answer (score 5):

`friend void testFriend(A in);` is unrelated to `B::testFriend`.

You can make the whole class friend instead:

```
class A {
   private:
      int x;
   public:
      A(int x) : x(x) {}
      friend class B;
};

class B {
public:
   void testFriend(A a) { std::cout << a.x; }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

`void testFriend(A in);` refers to a function in the global scope. What you need is `void B::testFriend(A in);`. However, this will require `B` to already be declared and implemented.

But to implement `testFriend` in `B`, `A` must be declared so that you can use an `A` as a parameter. Plus, `A` must be implemented for you to use `A.in`. If you have separate headers and implementations for your classes this shouldn't be a problem.

However, if you decide to do this in one file, you'll need to declare and implement in this order:

```
class A;

class B {
  public:
    void testFriend(A in);
};

class A {
 private:
    int x;
 public:
    A(int x) {
        this->x = x;
    }
    friend void B::testFriend(A in);
};

void B::testFriend(A in) {
    printf("%d", in.x);
}
```

Comment: The only correct answer here right on the money. If I could I'd upvote it again